# display the elements of a quotient ring

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

How can I display the elements (polynomials) of the ring $$\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x^2+1\rangle$$ Is there a built-in function that displays them?

Comment: @user6014 I tried to make a program that displays all polynomials of the form $$ax^2+bx+c$$ where a,b and c are in $$\mathbb Z_3$$, but i want to know if there is another way in case i take a larger field or a larger degree polynomial

Comment: `Tuples[Range[p], deg]` for degree `deg` in Z mod `p`? Or the `Dot` product of that with `x^Range[0, 2]`?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2  I used Dot[Tuples[Range[0, 2], 3], x^Range[0, 2]]